# Intellij not compiling scala project

Tags: scala, maven-3, intellij-14

So I have made a Maven Scala Project in IntelliJ.

I used the scala-simple-archetype.

And now I get this:

```html
Error:scala: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.7.0-final-52.0'
 at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
 at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
 at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
 at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
 at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
 at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
 at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
 at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:33)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:87)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:44)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
 at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
 at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:23)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Could anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

I'm relatively new to scala and maven so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I just figured it out.
Thanks to this post: [Sbt doesn't compile...](https://github.com/jboner/akka-training/issues/1)

You have to change the Version of scala in your pom.xml file from ${scala.version} to 2.11.4 (or whatever the newest version is)

Comment: Yes, there are two alternatives. Using java 7, and scala 2.7.* or alternatively using java 8, and scala 2.11.*